# I did not understand this python syntax

Tags: uniswap, python, vyper, uniswapv3

we have:

[image]

what does `pa, pb = pb, pa` mean? Help me to understand this.

Answer (score 1):

The code `pa, pb = pb, pa` swaps the values stored in `pa` and `pb`

It's a faster way of writing something like:

```py
temp = pa
pa = pb
pb = temp
```

Comment: suppose `pa = x, pb = y`, then its says `pb = pb` means `y = y`, then `pa`, how it is swapping? i did not understand.

Comment: Here is a similar stackoverflow question with a more detailed answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14836228/is-there-a-standardized-method-to-swap-two-variables-in-python